# Fetch all the brands from the product array on the sub category page

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

An array of Products is fetched on the subcategory page but, how to get a distinct brand from such array?

```
$product_sub_categories = ProductsSubCategory::where('product_sub_category_slug', $slug)->first();
$products = Products::all()->where('subcategory_id', $product_sub_categories->id);
$brands = Brand::all()->where('id', $products->brand_id)->distinct();    //help here
```

Comment: Try using `->get()` at the end of `$brands` query.

Comment: have u build the relationship between brand and product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `where()` before the `get()` will improve the performance.

And you can use `pluck('brand_id')` on `$products` collection to get the `brand_ids`:

```php
$product_sub_categories = ProductsSubCategory::where('product_sub_category_slug', $slug)->first();

$products = Products::where('subcategory_id', $product_sub_categories->id)->get();

$brands = Brand::whereIn('id', $products->pluck('brand_id')->all())->get();
```

Comment: Worked, Thank you